Can I publish a SaaS Offer for FileHandler App registration?
Recently I have researched to develop FileHandler Add-In in App registration.
I want to publish a SaaS offering to the marketplace (App Source) for my app registration. Or at least we can publish it to gallery Microsoft Entra Gallery.
But, I see that Microsoft isn't onboarding new applications to Microsoft Entra gallery in FY25 (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing#submit...)
For publishing a SaaS offering, Does Microsoft allow us to publish a SaaS offering for App registration in 2024 and 2025? I didn't find any documentation about such restrictions like publishing to Microsoft Entra Gallery. Please help me confirm this.
